# insert value of check boxes without submitting

Tags: javascript

This is a form where classes and sections are getting selected.when a class is selected four sections  appear.i really need to know how can i take input from these check boxes and identify which section belongs to which class.please provide also any modification of this code if needed.
thank you

Untitled Document

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function showMe (it, box) { 
var vis = (box.checked) ? "block" : "none"; 
document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis; 
} 
function showMe2 (it) { 
var vis = document.getElementById(it).style.display 
if (vis == "block") { document.getElementById(it).style.display = "none"; } 
else { document.getElementById(it).style.display = "block"; } 
} 

</script>
<style type="text/css">

.divstyle
{
display: none;
border: 1px solid #000;
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input name="class[one]" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe('div1', this)" /> 
One</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="class[two]" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe('div1', this)" />
Two</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="class[three]" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe('div1', this)" />
Three</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="class[four]" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe('div1', this)" />
Four</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="class[five]" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe('div1', this)" /> 
Five
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="class[six]" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe('div1', this)" />
Six
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="class[seven]" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe('div1', this)" />
Seven</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="class[eight]" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe('div1', this)" />
Eight</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="class[nine]" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe('div1', this)" />
Nine</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="class[ten]" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe('div1', this)" />
Ten</td>
</tr>

</table>

<div class="divstyle" id="div1">
<table>
<td><input name="sec[a]" type="checkbox" value="" />a</td>
<td><input name="sec[b]" type="checkbox" value="" />b</td>
<td><input name="sec[c]" type="checkbox" value="" />c</td>
<td><input name="sec[d]" type="checkbox" value="" />d</td>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to know which checkbox was clicked?

Comment: yes. there are four 'section' check boxes for each 'class' check boxes.so i need to know if section 'a' is clicked then which class does it belong to.... please help me

Answer (score 0):

You could set ID's in the checkboxes and pass that to your function also.

```
<td><input id="ten" name="class[ten]" type="checkbox" onclick="showMe('div1', this)" />
Ten</td>
```

in function showMe

```
document.getElementById('checked_box').value = box.id;
```

Send the value to a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="checked_box" id="checked_box" value="" />
```

Not too sure on what you are trying to accomplish in the end but here is a start.

Comment: You can use jquery to find the selected checkbox
something like 
$("#ID_OF_TABLE input:checked").attr("id")
not sure if you want to change your language....  Im sure there is something similar for straight JS